# How to use powershell to tell when a series of files have finished being added to network

Tags: powershell

So I have a powershell script, mainly taken from a similar question here, that can detect when a certain type of file is added to a certain network and send emails when this happens:

```
Function Watcher{

param ($folder, $filter, $to, $Subject)



$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    EnableRaisingEvents = $true
}

$changeAction = [scriptblock]::Create('

        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"

        $Body = "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"

        Email $to $Subject $Body

 ')

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName "Created" -Action $changeAction


}
```

However, I want to modify this such that it can be useful for this application: right now there is a tool adding data (.datx files) to the network (several files per minute) and I would like to receive email notification the moment that the data is done being recorded. How can I most easily modify this such that when the initial watcher is triggered, it waits to see if it happens again and resets if so, but then continues if not? Or would creating a whole new script be best? Basically, how can I make the watcher activated by a lone .datx file being uploaded to the network, but not have it triggered by a stream of them (except for the very last one)

Comment: As an aside:  Note that it's better to use syntax `{ ... }` to create script block (literals) - no need for `[scriptblock]::Create()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following *batching* approach:

- Define the length of a sliding time window that resets if a new file is created within it; keep collecting events while ones arrive within that sliding window.

  - To prevent the collection from growing indefinitely, define a maximum batch size at which a batch is processed, even if further events are pending.
- Once the time window elapses without new events having arrived, process the batch at hand, i.e., the events collected so far, then start a new batch.
- **Caveat**:

  - The [`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher) class can report *duplicate* events.
  - The code below eliminates duplicates *in a given batch*, but not *across batches*, which would require quite a bit more effort - see the source-code comments.
- Implementation notes:

  - Instead of using an `-Action` script block passed to [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) to process the events, they are processed *synchronously* - with a timeout - in a [`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event) loop.
  - `Wait-Event` uses PowerShell's event *queue* and therefore usually doesn't miss events (although that can happen at the .NET level in high-volume situations); by contrast, the `FileSystemWatcher`'s similar [`WaitForChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged) method does *not* queue events and only reports a - single - event, if one happens to arrive while the method waits.

```
try {

  # Specify the target folder: the system's temp folder in this example.
  $dir = (Get-Item -EA Ignore temp:).FullName; if (-not $dir) { $dir = $env:TEMP }

  # Create and initialize the watcher.
  # Note the [ordered] to ensure that .EnableRaisingEvents is set last.
  $watcher = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher] [ordered] @{
    Filter              = '*.datx'
    Path                = $dir
    EnableRaisingEvents = $true
  }

  # To simulate file creation, create *.datx files in the folder printed
  # mentioned in the following status message.
  Write-Host "Watching $dir for creation of $($watcher.Filter) files..."

  # Register for (subscribe to) creation events:
  # Determine a unique event-source ID...
  [string] $sourceId = New-Guid
  # ... and register for the watcher's Created event with it.
  Register-ObjectEvent $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier $sourceId

  # Initialize the ordered hashtable that collects all file names for a single 
  # batch.
  # Note: Since any given file creation can trigger *multiple* events, we 
  #       use an ordered hashtable (dictionary) to ensure that each file is 
  #       only reported once.
  #       However, *across batches* duplicates can still occur - see below.
  $batch = [ordered] @{}

  # Determine the sliding time window during which newly created files are 
  # considered part of a single batch.
  # That is, once a file has been created, each additional file created
  # within that time window relative to previous file becomes part of the
  # same batch.
  # When a time window elapses without a new file having been created, the
  # batch is considered complete and processed - see max. batch-size exception
  # below.
  # IMPORTANT:
  #  * The granularity is *seconds*, so the time window must be at least 1 sec.
  #  * Seemingly independently of the length of this window, duplicate events
  #    are likely to occur across batches the less time has elapsed between
  #    the end of a batch and the start of a new one - see below.
  $batchTimeWindowSecs = 5

  # How many names to allow a batch to contain at most, even if more
  # files keep getting created in the sliding time window.
  $maxBatchSize = 100

  while ($true) {
    # Run indefinitely; use Ctrl-C to exit.

    # Wait for events in a sliding time window of $batchTimeWindowSecs length.
    # Note: Using Wait-Event in a loop (1 event per iteration) is *more* 
    #       predictable than the multi-event collecting Get-Event in terms of
    #       avoiding duplicates, but duplicates do still occur.
    $batch.Clear()
    while ($evt = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceId -Timeout $batchTimeWindowSecs) {
      $evt | Remove-Event  # By default, events linger in the queue; they must be removed manually.
      # Add the new file's name to the batch (unless already present)
      # IMPORTANT:
      #  * Duplicates can occur both in a single batch and across batches.
      #  * To truly weed out all duplicates, you'd have to create a session-level
      #    dictionary of the files' names and their creation timestamps.
      #    With high-volume file creation, this session-level dictionary could
      #    grow large; periodic removal of obsolete entries would help.
      $batch[$evt.SourceArgs.Name] = $null # dummy value; it is the *keys* that matter.
      Write-Host ✔ -NoNewline # status output: signal that a new file was created
      # If the max. batch size has been reached, submit the batch now, even if further
      # events are pending within the timeout window.
      if ($batch.Count -ge $maxBatchSize) { 
        Write-Warning "Max. batch size of $maxBatchSize reached; force-submitting batch."
        break
      }
    }

    # Completed batch available?
    if ($batch.Count) {      
      # Simulate processing the batch.
      Write-Host "`nBatch complete: Sending email for the following $($batch.Count) files:`n$($batch.Keys -join "`n")"                                            #`
      # Start a new batch.
      $batch.Clear()
    }
    else {
      Write-Host . -NoNewline # status output: signal that no new files were created in the most recent time window.
    }

  }

}
finally {
  # Clean up:
  # Unregister the event subscription.
  Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceId
  # Dispose of the watcher.
  $watcher.Dispose() 
}
```

---

Sample output from creating a batch of 3 files first, then another with 5:

```
Watching C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp for creation of *.datx files...
............✔✔✔
Batch complete: Sending email for the following 3 files:
1.datx
2.datx
3.datx
.✔✔✔✔✔
Batch complete: Sending email for the following 5 files:
4.datx
5.datx
6.datx
7.datx
8.datx
....................
```